# ISPN000580: Failed to migrate persisted data - upgrading to jboss/keycloak 13.0.1

Tags: jboss, wildfly, keycloak, infinispan

I am trying to upgrade jboss/keycloak 6.0.1 to 13.0.1 which is running as StatefulSet in k8s. I have converted my standalone-ha.xml and I am getting the following error:

```
[0m[32m13:05:34,632 DEBUG [org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) PersistenceManagerImpl encountered an exception during startup of stores: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: ISPN000580: Failed to migrate persisted data.
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1739)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextReferenceExecutor.execute(ContextReferenceExecutor.java:49)
at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextualExecutor$1.run(ContextualExecutor.java:70)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: ISPN000580: Failed to migrate persisted data.
at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore.migrateFromV1(SingleFileStore.java:373)
at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore.start(SingleFileStore.java:160)
at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.persistence.support.NonBlockingStoreAdapter.lambda$start$0(NonBlockingStoreAdapter.java:108)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
... 7 more
Caused by: protostream.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
at org.infinispan.protostream@4.3.5.Final//protostream.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:102)
at org.infinispan.protostream@4.3.5.Final//protostream.com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:627)
at org.infinispan.protostream@4.3.5.Final//org.infinispan.protostream.impl.RawProtoStreamReaderImpl.readTag(RawProtoStreamReaderImpl.java:45)
at org.infinispan.protostream@4.3.5.Final//org.infinispan.protostream.WrappedMessage.readMessage(WrappedMessage.java:275)
at org.infinispan.protostream@4.3.5.Final//org.infinispan.protostream.ProtobufUtil.fromWrappedByteArray(ProtobufUtil.java:162)
at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.PersistenceMarshallerImpl.objectFromByteBuffer(PersistenceMarshallerImpl.java:155)
at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore.migrateFromV1(SingleFileStore.java:333)
... 10 more
```

Any idea how to tackle this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due the cache. In order to make it work the cache will need to be migrated from the syntax that keycloak 6 uses to 13. In our case, we preferred to start with a new cache.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30705417)

Answer (score 2):

Do you try to update your Keycloak system while still running any instances? This is not supported by Keycloak. It's recommended to shut down all instances and start migration with one instance, when upgrading major versions!

Between Keycloak 6 and 13 the underlying Infinispan versions have changed and thus at some point also the de-/serialization mechanism. Most possibly that's the cause for your errors.

Comment: Thanks dasinko
I am scaling down all instances to 0, deploying the new keycloak, and then scale up only to 1.
I have manged to do the upgrade by running the keycloak on a new volume that does not contain the cache and it works. This tells me that the problem is infact the infispan migration.
Do you have any tips how to migrate the cache-containers there?

Comment: Standard Keycloak containers don't persist the cache anywhere. So if you shut all instances gracefully down and start with one node, it should work. If you modified how Infinispan works with Keycloak or if you are using an external Infinispan cluster, you have to make sure that all information is being evicted.

Comment: Thanks agin for your reply.
In our configuration of infinispan, we used a persistent volume that contains all the cache. All the pods are connected to it. The infinispan was upgraded from version 8 (which was used in keycloak 6.0.1) to 12. If I start keycloak 13, with the persistent volume that contains keycloak 6 cache I get the error I started my question with. If I start with a new volume that has no cache, then it works. This tells me a migration process is due. I still do not know how to set it up. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Official solution from Red Hat:

*Delete saved web session data by removing all of the the contents of the directory
$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/data/infinispan/web*